# enemy ship rotates towards the player but does not lock into position

Tags: c#, monogame

when my enemy ship moves towards the player i find the distance between them with

```
private float FindDistance(Vector2 heroCenter, Vector2 spritePos)
{
    var deltaX = Math.Pow((spritePos.X - heroCenter.X), 2); // the 2 is the power value (into the power of 2)
    var deltaY = Math.Pow((spritePos.Y - heroCenter.Y), 2);
    float distance = (float)Math.Sqrt(deltaX + deltaY);
    return distance; // returns the distance between the two objects
}
```

then I calculate the enemy ship angle of rotation with this code

```
distanceFromHero = FindDistance(Constants.heroCenter, spritePos);
if (distanceFromHero < Constants.HeroWithinRange)
{
    heroClose = true;
    VelocityX *= .985f; // enemy reduces vel X
    VelocityY *= .985f; // enemy reduces vel Y
    //atan2 for angle
    var radians = Math.Atan2((spritePos.Y - Constants.heroCenter.Y), (spritePos.X - Constants.heroCenter.X));
    //radians into degrees
    rotationAngle = (float)(radians * (180 / Math.PI));
}
else
{
    heroClose = false;
}
```

but strangely the enemy though moving towards the player does not lock on and stay steady but does a pendulum like movement and when they at the same point the enemy ship rotate endlessly. Some help with code would help.

Comment: you want the sprite to stop moving and just rotate toward the "hero"?

Comment: I'm guessing based on your code, if the sprite are close enough to the hero, it would turn towards the hero -- slowing down -- and eventually hit the hero. The problem is that instead of a single straight line towards the hero, it actually making a zig-zag move. Furthermore when it arrives at the hero, it keep on spinning

Comment: A hunch about the zig-zag move and possibly the spinning is related with the rounding on float (eg: 43.65+61.11=104.75999999999999). May be to stop the spinning, you could add another logic (ie: distanceFromHero < 0.1 -- assume that the sprite had reached your hero).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The perfect answer to my question i found in an XBox forum which couldn't loaded into Visual Studio 2017 so I made a new solution. Hope others can benefit from this excellent tutorial made by Microsoft. The Solution is [here.](https://bitbucket.org/diliupg/microsft_catmousetank_wanderchaseevade_updatedforvs2017)

Comment: Could you rather provide the direct answer to the question instead of needing to search for it?